# How to get the reversed result of the following regex?

Tags: regex

Regex: `/^[0-9\p{L}.,\s]+$/u`

I would like to replace the characters not matching with the regex with "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you simply want to drop all chars not matching your regex. So the idea is to invert the class of chars:

`/^[0-9\p{L}.,\s]+$/u` should become `/[^\d\p{L}.,\s]+/gu` (I added the `^` after the `[` to say *"not in this list of chars"* and replaced `0-9` by `\d` for digits. Use the `g` modifier (=**g**lobal  ) to match multiple times.

Running it: https://regex101.com/r/IQz6K5/1

I'm not sure that `,`, `.` and the space will be enough ponctuation. It would be interesting to have a complete example of what you are trying to achieve. You could use another unicode character class for ponctuation if needed, typically with `\p{P}`. See more info about unicode classes here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category

Comment: Thanks Patrick! It works. I implemented the regex into the onChange of the input tag as: `const onChange = (e) => {  const result = e.target.value.replace(regex, "");  setValue(result);  };`  However a special character e.g. `^`  is shown if I type it as the first letter. It will not be shown if only I type it as the second letter or so on.

Comment: Great it helped you. Well, you could use the *keypress* event and then check `event.key` which contains the character pressed. If it's not allowed then you have to simply do `event.preventDefault()` so that the char doesn't appear. But keep the *change* event listener as the user could still copy-paste a value.